# Formatos de fechas en Python

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

Tengo un problema con las fechas en python. Tengo un dataframe que contiene una columna llamada Date con este formato:

2020-08-23 22:00:16

Quiero saber el formato que tiene:

```
df.Date.dtype
```

output:

```
dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

Ni idea de qué formato es, la verdad.

El asunto es que necesito filtrar el df. Supongamos que tengo en el df filas con fechas que van del día 1 al día 31 (hoy es día 31). Necesito tomar las filas con fechas relativas a los 7 días previos a la fecha de hoy (es decir, del 24 al 31).

Para ello, hago esto:

```
import datetime

lista= []
hoy = datetime.date.today()
siete_dias = hoy - datetime.timedelta(days=7)
mylist.append(siete_dias)
print (lista[0])
```

output:

```
2020-08-24
```

Con esto último, tengo la fecha de hoy.

Lo que pretendo hacer, pues, es un filtro para seleccionar, en mi df, las filas que tengan una fecha mayor a la que acabo de poner (2020-08-24). Lo hago así dado que la consulta relativa a los últimos 7 días se hará de forma periódica y la selección de los últimos 7 días tiene que ser automática.

Por ello, hago lo siguiente:

```
df_siete_dias=df.loc[df["Date"]>(mylist[0])].copy()
```

Output: un error:

```
TypeError: Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date
```

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esto? No encuentro forma de hacerlo funcionar.

Muchas muchas gracias!

Un saludo,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es transformar a tu variable `hoy` en `datetime`, ya que actualmente la defines como `date`, y por tal motivo te arroja la excepción de que no posible comparar distintos tipos de datos.

Sólo tiene que definirla asi:

```
hoy = datetime.datetime.today()
```

desconozco para que utilizas `mylist`, pero creo que puedes usar directamente

```
df_siete_dias=df.loc[df["Date"]>siete_dias].copy()
```

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias!!!